# Can workers keep overpaid salary?

Tags: contract-law, corporate-law, payment, salary, employee

[Technical issues caused salaries of employees to be mixed up in a South Korean company.](https://www.seoulwire.com/news/articleView.html?idxno=503071)

> 22일 직장인 커뮤니티 블라인드 게시글 등에 따르면 지난 19일 “명세서에 적힌 금액보다 덜 들어왔다”는 효성 직원들의 게시글이 올라왔다.

> On an online employee forum posts claiming that Hyoseong employees "received less then that written on my receipt" surfaced.

> 게시판에는 “부장이 사원 월급을 받고 사원이 부장 월급을 받았다”, “말단 사원인데 급여가 1000만원 넘게 찍혔다”, “기분 좋다 말았다. 특별 보너스인 줄” 등의 글이 올라왔다. 현재 효성 직원들이 직접 올린 게시글은 모두 삭제된 상태다.

> On message boards posts such as "I am a new employee and I got paid more than $7500" were uploaded. The posts are no longer available.

> 효성그룹 측은 “계열사인 효성티앤씨 본사 직원들을 상대로 전산 오류가 있었다”며 “원래 급여보다 많이 받은 분들에게서 회입(도로 거둬들임)하고 적게 받은 분들에게 돌려드리는 식으로 해결된 상황”이라고 밝혔다.

> Hyoseong revealed that "there was a technical issue" and added "the situation has been resolved by recovering overpayments and compensating underpayments".

However if someone got overpaid so much and does not plan on working in the company for a long period of time, they might decide that they want to keep it. Would certain jurisdictions allow this behavior? To be more specific, are there jurisdictions in which employees can do one or more of the following:

1. Keep the overpaid salary and continue working in the company as if nothing happened with no repercussions
2. Quit immediately and keep the overpaid salary without being charged or chased by law enforcement